# Android Emulator is not getting started automatically when running simple appium on windows machines

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator, appium

Android Emulator is not getting started automatically when running simple appium test. Eventhough I am setting both “avd” and “deviceName” capability. This works fine on mac and linux machines but does not work on windows machines.

I am using appium version 1.19